# ajaxで意図した配列データを渡したい

Tags: php, jquery

ajaxで配列データを渡したいのでうまくいっていません。
下記のようなコードを実行すると、PHPで `$_GET` を出力すると結果が

```
array(
  [test_input%5Bhome%5D] =chintai,
  [val] => 99
)
```

となってしまいます。理想としては

```
array(
  [test_input] => array (
     [home] => chintai,
  )
    [val] => 99
)
```

となってほしいのですがどのように修正すればよいでしょうか。Jqueryのバージョンは1.9です。

```
var test_input ={};
var paramName ='home';
test_input[paramName] = 'chintai';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "割愛",
    data: { 
        test_input,
        val: 99 },
    dataType : "json",

success: function (data) {
    $("#results").append(data);
},
error: function () {
    alert("読み込み失敗");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のような　dataを指定すると urlエンコードされたパラメーターは、`/?argv={"test_input":{"home":"chintai"},"val":99}`として送信されます。

```
 data:{"argv":'{"test_input":{"home":"chintai"},"val":99}'},
```

または、   `data:{"argv":オブジェクト変数},` でも同様に送れると思います。

だだし、`＄_GET['argv']` の文字列（json）を　json_decodeすると{}で囲まれているので、以下のような　オブジェクト（stdClass Object）になります。

```
stdClass Object
(
    [test_input] => stdClass Object
        (
            [home] => chintai
        )

    [val] => 99
)
```